# sorting of edges of polygon

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting, computational-geometry

Let us consider the vertices of the non-self intersecting polygon as 
1.(x_1,y_1)
2.(x_2,y_2),...,6.(x_6,y_6).

We are also given with the pair points which form the edges of the polygon in a array.
The array is  {(1,4),(2,6),(2,5),(4,3),(6,1),(3,5)}'. Note that this edges are not consecutive and (x,y)=(y,x).

I need an algorithm to get array of the type $ (1,4),(4,3),(3,5),(5,2),(2,6),(6,1)$, so that I can get the consecutive edges one by another.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not provide a data structure for you polygon coordinates, so I assume that they are stored in a `data.frame`.

**Data**

```
d <- data.frame(from = c(1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 3), to = c(4, 6, 5, 3, 1, 5))
```

**Code**

```
getEdgesOrdered <- function(current, rest, result = list(unlist(current))) {
   if (NROW(rest) == 0) {
      result
   } else {
      to <- current$to
      wh <- match(to, rest$from)
      if (is.na(wh)) {
         wh <- match(to, rest$to)
         elem <- setNames(rest[wh, c("to", "from")], c("from", "to"))
      } else {
         elem <- rest[wh, c("from", "to")]
      }
      Recall(elem, rest[-wh, ], c(result, list(unlist(elem))))
   }
}

getEdgesOrdered(d[1,], d[-1,])
```

**Explanation**

The function takes the first edge and looks up the `to` node in the `from` column in the remaining `data.frame`. If it is not found there, it looks it up in the `to` column. The current edge is then appended to the result vector, the found edge is removed from the `data.frame` and it is the new edge to look up. When there are no rows left in the `data.frame` the algorithm stops and returns the search path.

Comment: Great answer. It is working and the explanation is very clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for late tick marking. Actually I was unaware of this tick marking. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are working with graph-like data so perhaps the `igraph` package might be helpful.

```
points<-rbind(c(1,4),c(2,6),c(2,5),c(4,3),c(6,1),c(3,5))

library(igraph)
plot(minimum.spanning.tree(graph.edgelist(points)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I am working with graph like data. From data it seems that, 2 and 5 are connecting node but this graph not showing that connection. Could you please explain what we are missing.

Comment: i created a minimum spanning tree so you loose the circularity (as in your example). If you want to preserve that aspect, just use `plot(graph.edgelist(points))`

Answer (score 0):

Scan the edge list and fill two arrays: at index `i`, store the indexes of the two vertexes linked to vertex `i`, let  `p[N]` and `q[N]` (initialize `p` and `q` with a reserved value meaning "unknown yet"). This takes linear time.

Then starting from `(i, j):= (1, p[1])`, find the next edge: if `p[j] == i`, then `(j, q[j])` else `(j, p[j])`. Repeat until `j == 1`. This also takes linear time.

In your case:

```
1 -> 4, 6
2 -> 6, 5
3 -> 4, 5
4 -> 1, 3
5 -> 3, 2
6 -> 2, 1
```

The cycle is `1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6`.